# Battleship in C, random ship placement

Tags: c

So, I'm making a user vs computer battleship game, using a 10x10 array as the board. I want to place two ships randomly on the board (one size-5 arrays nad the other size-4). What I did was randomly generate 0 or 1, 0 is vertical placement and 1 is horizontal. Then using a while loop I check whether the generated numbers fit the board and on the ship with size 4 I also have to check whether the numbers generated were already used for the first ship. I did this using a seperate function. The program gives problems when one ship is being placed vertically, and I can't figure out why. When it's placed vertically, it only makes a ship with size-3.
Here is the code:

```
   void startShips(int ships[][2]){
        srand(time(NULL));
        int n1,n2;
        n1 = rand()%2;
        n2 = rand()%2;
        //0=vertical, 1=horizontal

            if(n1==0){
                do{
                ships[0][0]= rand()%10;
                ships[0][1]= rand()%10;
                ships[1][0]= ships[0][0]+1;
                ships[1][1]= ships[0][1];
                ships[2][0]= ships[0][0]+2;
                ships[2][1]= ships[0][1];
                ships[3][0]= ships[0][0]+3;
                ships[3][1]= ships[0][1];
                ships[4][0]= ships[0][0]+4;
                ships[4][1]= ships[0][1];
                }while(ships[4][0]>9);
            }
            if(n1==1){
                do{
                ships[0][0]= rand()%10;
                ships[0][1]= rand()%10;
                ships[1][0]= ships[0][0];
                ships[1][1]= ships[0][1]+1;
                ships[2][0]= ships[0][0];
                ships[2][1]= ships[0][1]+2;
                ships[3][0]= ships[0][0];
                ships[3][1]= ships[0][1]+3;
                ships[4][0]= ships[0][0];
                ships[4][1]= ships[0][1]+4;
                }while(ships[4][1]>9);
            }

             if(n2==0){
                do{
                ships[5][0]= rand()%10;
                ships[5][1]= rand()%10;
                ships[6][0]= ships[5][0]+1;
                ships[6][1]= ships[5][1];
                ships[7][0]= ships[5][0]+2;
                ships[7][1]= ships[5][1];
                ships[8][0]= ships[5][0]+3;
                ships[8][1]= ships[0][1];
                }while((ships[8][0]>9) ||
                       (checkShip(ships)==1)
                    );
            }
            if(n2==1){
                do{
                ships[5][0]= rand()%10;
                ships[5][1]= rand()%10;
                ships[6][0]= ships[5][0];
                ships[6][1]= ships[5][1]+1;
                ships[7][0]= ships[5][0];
                ships[7][1]= ships[5][1]+2;
                ships[8][0]= ships[5][0];
                ships[8][1]= ships[0][1]+3;
                }while((ships[8][1]>9) ||
                        (checkShip(ships)==1)
                       );
            }

    }
int checkShip(int ships[][2]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5 ; i++){
        if((ships[5][0]==ships[i][0])&&(ships[5][1]==ships[i][1])){
            return 1;
            break;}
        }
        for(i=0;i<5 ; i++){
        if((ships[6][0]==ships[i][0])&&(ships[6][1]==ships[i][1])){
            return 1;
            break;}
        }
        for(i=0;i<5 ; i++){
        if((ships[7][0]==ships[i][0])&&(ships[7][1]==ships[i][1])){
            return 1;
            break;}
        }
        for(i=0;i<5 ; i++){
        if((ships[8][0]==ships[i][0])&&(ships[8][1]==ships[i][1])){
            return 1;
            break;}
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a typo in your vertical handling

```
   ...
   ships[7][1]= ships[5][1];
   ships[8][0]= ships[5][0]+3;
   ships[8][1]= ships[0][1];
                     ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Ha! I was just looking for something like that. Also `ships[8][1]= ships[0][1]+3;` in next code block.